# What has more force/power?

Tags: forces

Imagine two mountain rams fighting it off for a female on a slope. (staircase-ish) If they were to butt heads, which would be able to use more power? Which is more advantageous in the battle?

Comment: I'm pretty sure both answers would be the bottom goat, but can someone provide a a better physics answer?

Comment: When they hit, by Newton's 3rd law they'll exert forces of the same magnitude on each other. Apart from that, it's probably down to the criteria for victory in these confrontations and other details that actually belong to biology.

Comment: The top one will have extra available potential energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ram that is butting "down" is able to pick up some speed from gravity. On the other hand, the lower ram is able to stand his ground better - as the upper ram pushes him, his hooves are in effect digging into the ground.

In a "locked horns" battle I would say the lower ram can lift the upper ram by just pushing - but not the other way around. So the details of the setup and assumptions can change the answer; this is why a good diagram can help with the question.